# Huawei Phone not appearing in Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, instant-run

My Huawei P8 lite smartphone is not appearing in Android Studio on Windows 10. Although internal memory of mobile is appearing and file transfer is possible.

Here's things I have tried.

1. Connected my phone to other laptops. It's working fine.
2. Connected other phones to my laptop. They are working fine.
3. Tried multiple data cables.
4. Updated all my drivers using Driver Booster.
5. Installed the latest version of Android Studio.
6. Updated my Windows.
7. Reset my Phone to Factory Defaults.
8. Manually installed ADB and USB drivers for Huawei.
9. Tried to update my USB driver in Device Manager but doesn't get updated that way.

Comment: make sure you have enabled USB debugging

Comment: Yes I have enabled USB debugging.

Answer (score 3):

My device is a Huawei Nova 2i phone and I had to face some difficulties to get it listed under available devices. USB debug option was getting disabled automatically and I had to follow below mentioned steps to fix it.
First connect the android device via usb cable and enable the "transfer files" option.
After that enable USB debug in developer option menu.
After the above configurations, my device was listed in target devices.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you download [HiSuite](http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/HiSuite_en/), which is an official management tool.
After connecting device with PC, check "**Transfer files**" option.
you could enter this setting via swiping down notifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't connect **Huawei** phones to **Android Studio**, You can give it a try.

Follow these simple steps:

First you need to turn on Developer mode. To turn on developer mode go to **Settings**-> **About phone** -> click **Build number** **7** times .You will see a message "You are now a developer".

Next Steps: Find your Developer option. It Should be in **System & update** -> **Developer Options**

1. Turn on **USB debugging**
2. **Select USB configuration** -> **Choose Media Transfer Protocol(MTP)**

Then you might see a alert about "**Allow USB debugging**" Click **OK**.
You are good to go. If these steps doesn't help you, please change your cable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Huawei P9. Then I realized that on **device manager**, my phone was using the incorrect driver. After I picked the **MTP USB DRIVER**, it worked.

[image]